# how to set two 'select 'components in same line, using tcomd-form-native

Tags: react-native, tcomb-form-native

I am building a doctor registration form, what I want is to display start time and end time in the same line, I'm using tcomb-form-native library, in the docs i didn't find the way to set felx 1 and felxdirection to row for a select component. I did my work using normal Picker component but the problem is that when the state of picker component changes, it clears the whole tcomb form.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see your code. I can't tell you clearly but try this.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
   <View style={{ width: 100}}>
      <Form/>
   </View>
  <View style={{ width: 100}}>
      <Form/>
   </View>
</View>
```